# How to stop scrolling in ListView?

Tags: xml, android-studio

I want the `listview` not to be scrolled and the items to be displayed in it normally; then I can manage the scrolling with `ScrollView`.

**look the codes:**

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/submit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/submit"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_success"
                android:gravity="center"

                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"/>
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@color/Color_Red"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this method to your view, it will stop scrolling,

```
listView.smoothScrollBy(0, 0);
```